# Fire event when menu is outside viewport and fix menu to top of viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `menu` element that I want to become fixed to the top of the browser viewport if the `menu` element becomes *outside* the viewport due to scrolling. Conceptually, my web page looks something like the example HTML below where the menu is below an some text in the header. Once the user scrolls past the header the menu should become fixed to the top of the browser viewport so that the menu is always visible. Similarly, the menu should go back to the non-fixed posisiton if the user scrolls upwards so that the header becomes visible in the browser viewport again.

Update:
The design requirements are that the menu should be below the header as it contains some important message that must be read before the menu, only when you scroll past the header should the menu be fixed at the top of the browser viewport.

I'm guessing that I need JQuery to make this work? Could someone post some examples, please.

```
<html>
<body>
<header id="header">Header text...
   <menu id="menu"><a href="/">Home</a> | <a href="/Help">Help</a></menu>
</header>
<section id="more">More text...</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can include `css` , `js` tried at Question ?

Comment: @guest271314 Have not tried anything yet because I have not found a solution. It is not a bug I'm facing but how to conceptually solve the problem at hand. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is just an example how it could be done via jQuery.Just add 4 , 5 paragraphs with a text below your header to see how it works.
There's an example below via codepen.

HTML:

```
  <header>
      <div class="logo">STICKY MENU ON SCROLL!</div>
      <div class="intro">Some dumbass tagline goes here</div>
      <div class="menu">Menu goes here - home - links - blah blah</div>
    </header>
```

CSS:

```
.logo {font-size:40px; font-weight:bold;color:#00a; font-style:italic;}
.intro {color:#777; font-style:italic; margin:10px 0;}
.menu {background:#00a; color:#fff; height:40px; line-height:40px;letter-spacing:1px; width:100%;}
```

JS:

```
$('.menu').addClass('original').clone().insertAfter('.menu').addClass('cloned').css('position','fixed').css('top','0').css('margin-top','0').css('z-index','500').removeClass('original').hide();

scrollIntervalID = setInterval(stickIt, 10);


function stickIt() {

  var orgElementPos = $('.original').offset();
  orgElementTop = orgElementPos.top;               

  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= (orgElementTop)) {
    // scrolled past the original position; now only show the cloned, sticky element.

    // Cloned element should always have same left position and width as original element.     
    orgElement = $('.original');
    coordsOrgElement = orgElement.offset();
    leftOrgElement = coordsOrgElement.left;  
    widthOrgElement = orgElement.css('width');
    $('.cloned').css('left',leftOrgElement+'px').css('top',0).css('width',widthOrgElement).show();
    $('.original').css('visibility','hidden');
  } else {
    // not scrolled past the menu; only show the original menu.
    $('.cloned').hide();
    $('.original').css('visibility','visible');
  }
}
```

[HERE IS THE DEMO](http://codepen.io/senff/pen/ayGvD)